How schedule Analyze jobs using procedure and pass the schemas from parameters?
I want to schedule the analyze jobs which are skipped from auto analyze I wrote procedure to do that.
I want to pass the parameters (schema) while calling procedure.
But I am facing the error not able to pass
I have tried below procedure but getting error while executing.
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE analyze_specific_schemas(schemas_to_process VARCHAR)
AS $$
DECLARE
   schemaname VARCHAR;
   tablename VARCHAR;
BEGIN
   FOR schema_name IN 
       SELECT DISTINCT value
       FROM STRING_SPLIT(schemas_to_process, ',')
   LOOP
       FOR table_name IN 
           SELECT DISTINCT tablename
           FROM SVV_TABLE_INFO
           WHERE stats_off > 5
           AND schema = schema_name
       LOOP
           EXECUTE 'ANALYZE VERBOSE "' || schemaname  || '"."' || tablename || '"';
       END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

